# How can I combine alt-fire and fire(of 2 different weapons) into a single button press?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I have 2 weapons for Scout, the Flying Guillotine and the Sandman. And since the sandman can Stun, and the Guillotine does crits vs. stunned players, I thought it would be really cool if I could bind the Middle mouse button to hit the ball and then throw the Guillotine.

However, this is not working. Could anyone help out?

I realised the code I had given previously was wrong, so I've removed it. Now I only need to know how to Alt-Fire the sandman and fire the Guillotine by pressing one button only. I now know how to do it using multiple buttons.

I've using these 2 websites for the scripting code:

- [TF2 Wiki: Scripting - Aliasing](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Scripting#Console_Commands)
- [Valve: Console Commands](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Console_Command_List)

Comment: Be aware that servers can disable the `wait` command.

Comment: If there is anything that needs to be changed or something like that please tell me and I will change it.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: @JawwadLateef - Can you provide your updated code?

Comment: @Robotnik I am yet to test the code. When I do so I will update it here.

Comment: @JawwadLateef - Ok. Once tested, if you give us what you've got as a baseline we'd be in a better position to help you.

Comment: @Robotnik I tried binding the sandman ball to '2' and the guillotine to '3', but I found out that I have to press and hold for it to work,(which I do not want). So I guess you could say that there is no other code

Answer (score 1):

What i and a lot of other people do for this kind of thing is use external macro-software and other things similar to that to perform these actions for us.

There is lots of software that can be found on the internet that can do this sort of thing. Like https://www.jitbit.com/macro-recorder/ for instance. The best thing to do is look around and see what works best for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a *Corsair* keyboard or mouse with buttons, then I would assume you have already thought about this, but just in case, I'll post it anyway.

You can use the *Corsair Utility Engine* (CUE) to create a macro. I personally have the *K95 RGB* and use the function/G keys on the left of the keyboard for a variety of macros. In my opinion, this is the quickest solution however, this obviously assumes you have a *Corsair* keyboard and or mouse.

Coincidentally, *Corsair* Keyboards are **on sale today**, August 14th, 2017 on Amazon. They are the deal of the day:  [Amazon Deal of the Day](https://www.amazon.com/s/browse?ie=UTF8&node=16352389011&ref=bit_aa_dotd_cta_two_buttons&tag=amz-mkt-chr-us-20&ascsubtag=1ba00-01000-a0049-def00-other-nomod-us000-gatwy-feature-DOTDC)